# What's the difference between "get_posts" and "wp_get_recent_posts" when used with "setup_postdata"?

Tags: get-posts, recent-posts

This might be a completely "I'm still new to WP" type question, but I ran into some interesting output when using [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) and [`wp_get_recent_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts) in a custom function I wrote with [`setup_postdata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata). Here's what I had in my *functions.php* file:

```
<?php
function getRecentPosts($total_posts = 2)
{
    $total_posts = intval($total_posts);
    global $post;

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => $total_posts,
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'post_status'    => 'publish'
    );
    $posts = get_posts($args);

    foreach ($posts as $post)
    {
        setup_postdata($post);
        echo '<div>';
            the_title();
        echo '</div>';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Simple, right? And that function works great, throwing out title's inside `div` tags perfectly. But when I replace lines 7-12 with the following:

```
    ...
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => $total_posts,
        //'post_type'    => 'post',
        'post_status'    => 'publish'
    );
    $posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);
    ...
```

...then the function doesn't seem to "iterate" through the posts correctly, throwing out the first post it finds' title over and over, much like if you don't use `global $post` at the beginning of the function.

Why is this? Is there something different that `wp_get_recent_posts()` does that I do not yet understand.

Comment: try `$posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args, '');` $post global var should be an object. `wp_get_recent_posts` as default output posts as array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [source](http://queryposts.com/function/setup_postdata/) of `setup_postdata()` you'll find that it requires an object (`$post`), to be passed, not an array.

`wp_get_recent_posts()` ([source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.6/wp-includes/post.php#L2558)), by default (for pre 3.1 backwards compatibilty) returns each post as an array. The second, optional argument, that can be passed to `wp_get_recent_posts()` can prevent this:

`$posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args, OBJECT_K )`

(though any value other than `ARRAY_A` in the second argument will do).

Comment: Happy to see this is the exact thing I've said in my comment. :)

Comment: @G.M. Indeed, your comment is the correct answer :)

Comment: Thank you both! I feel like I could've researched this a little better, but I'm learning something new every day! :)

Comment: @Chris - If in doubt, just check the source :). [queryposts.com](http://queryposts.com) is *incredibly* useful for that. (Second only to a decent IDE).

Comment: @StephenHarris Oh wooooow O__O ! Clearly I'm still learning! ;)